# Затемнение области как в Dialog окнах

Tags: android

Как можно реализовать затемнение области экрана как при диалоговых окнах?
И так же что бы по темной области нельзя было взять какой либо объект в фокус.

Comment: Почему то нельзя использовать активити с темой Dialog? Если да, то почему, уточните задачу.

Comment: По тапу на заголовок тулбара выезжает скрытая его часть с доп меню, и вот в этот момент нужно затенить все кроме тулбара.

Answer (score 1):

Добавить `layout` с полупрозрачным фоном на все окно и делать его видимым когда нужно?